# Grizzly Jersey - Only @Path("/") works

Tags: java, jersey, grizzly

I try to run a Jersey(1.17) resource on a Grizzly(2.2.21) server using HTTPS and Basic Auth and get everything working except the resource.

```
@Path("/")
public class Helloworld {

    @GET
    public String helloworld2() {
        return "asdf2";
    }

    @Path("helloworld")
    @GET
    public String helloworld() {
        return "asdf";
    }
}
```

Yea it's just the Helloworld example and it still freaks me out.
I can access localhost:port/ and it works fine, but localhost:port/somethingother also returns "asdf2". Especially localhost:port/helloworld also returns "asdf2".

I also tryed

```
@Path("/")
public class Helloworld {

   @GET
   @Path("/helloworld")
   public String helloworld() {
      return "asdf";
   }
}
```

and

```
@Path("/helloworld")
public class Helloworld {

   @GET
   public String helloworld() {
      return "asdf";
   }
}
```

In both cases i get 404 in Firebug for every request.

Does someone has a solution?
Thx

Edit:

To create the server and so on i use this example code (without the server truststore):
https://svn.java.net/svn/jersey~svn/trunk/jersey/samples/https-clientserver-grizzly/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/samples/https_grizzly/

Comment: Have you tried to query localhost:port/helloworld/helloworld? (Ed - With the first of you versions given in the question of course ...)

Comment: @Fildor
Using the first version i get:
localhost:port/helloworld/helloworld -> "asdf2"
localhost:port/helloworld/helloworld/ -> 404
localhost:port/helloworld/helloworld/something -> "asdf2"

Comment: pls share the registration/initialization part of the code

Comment: @geozwey pls try to add this line to the initialization code:         registration.addMapping("/*");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `registration.addMapping("/*");` to my initialization code worked.

Thanks ver much alexey